# How to execute JMXterm with inline script using -cp?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jmx, mbeans

In a batch file I want to use jmxterm to access jboss mbeans.
Therefore I need to include jboss-eap-6.1\bin\client\jboss-client.jar to the classpath.

So I need to call jmxterm that way to get it to work:

> java -cp
>   .;%JBOSSDIR%/bin/client/jboss-client.jar;jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar
>   org.codehaus.classworlds.uberjar.boot.Bootstrapper --url
>   service:jmx:remoting-jmx://localhost:9999

The problem: I need to pass an argument to the MBean method I want to call. So I only see the option to pass the script inline but don't know how to do that.

I found that it should work by piping the jmxterm command to the jmxterm call. Adapted to my case (using -cp instead of -jar) it doesn't work:

> echo "bean  run " | java -cp
>   .;%JBOSSDIR%/bin/client/jboss-client.jar;jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar
>   org.codehaus.classworlds.uberjar.boot.Bootstrapper --url
>   service:jmx:remoting-jmx://localhost:9999 -n

I get the following output:

```
Feb 04, 2015 3:26:00 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
Feb 04, 2015 3:26:00 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
Feb 04, 2015 3:26:00 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.16.GA-redhat-1
Welcome to JMX terminal. Type "help" for available commands.
#IllegalArgumentException: Command "bean isn't valid, run help to see available commands
```

Passing the script as file works but I need to pass the script inline to pass parameters to the mbean method calls.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean with *pass the script as file*, but you can give all the execution information as a file in the call:

```
java -cp .;%JBOSSDIR%/bin/client/jboss-client.jar;jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar 
org.codehaus.classworlds.uberjar.boot.Bootstrapper -v silent -n < commands.txt
```

And then having a commands.txt as this:

```
open -u service:jmx:remoting-jmx://localhost:9999
run -b com.your.package:type=BeanName methodName parameter1
close
```